# Default Share Configuration

Tags: windows-server-2008

I need to install Oracle database 11.2 on Windows Server 2008 R2.  The prerequisite check requires that the system drive has the default share configured. I applied this command:

```
net use \\localhost\c$
```

But I receive error `network path not found`

What do I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Related answer? [Can't connect to default admin share on Windows 2008](http://serverfault.com/questions/38999/cant-connect-to-default-admin-share-on-windows-2008/39101#39101)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a second "\", as in *net view \\localhost*.

Even though there's not listing for the admi share of C$, when I run *net use v: \\localhost\c$ /persistent:no* I get a remapped version of C: on V:

Comment: the second '\' is in OP's source, markdown may have mis-parsed it.  I will edit the question to clean up formatting.

Comment: Yep...looks like it wiped mine too, which I have fixed.

Comment: I also wasn't looking at the right command.  Let me try without a drive letter, which now I see also works without trouble.

Comment: `NET SHARE` should list local shares, including admin shares.